# Use version control for multiple IPtables

Tags: version-control, iptables

I have multiple servers each running specific *iptables* rule sets. I also have *rancid* backing up network gear configs. I really like the way *rancid* works and I am wondering if anyone has done this for *iptables* rule sets on RHEL boxes.

Has anyone written *rancid* plugins to pull *iptables* conf files from servers in the same way *rancid* pulls network configs?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: I actually decommissioned rancid for network backups. I ended up using a little script and cron jobs to back up iptables to a git repo. Works pretty good and use it on all servers that have iptables running

Comment: Willing to share the script?

Comment: it is a pretty simple script assuming you have your git repo created.

formatting was messed up when i posted the code, here is script on  [gist](https://gist.github.com/mylivingweb/4b4fee763d14d64b1b7a)